# How certain is the heat death of the universe?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, entropy, universe

According to our current scientific knowledge, how certain is it that [heat death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe) shall be the ultimate fate of our universe, and why? Are there any serious hypotheses competing with heat death, and if such hypotheses exist, what are they based on?

Comment: Heat death occurs in a closed system. The universe seems open.

Comment: Do you mean open/closed in a thermodynamic sense or the "shape" of the universe? In my understanding the heat death is expected to happen also with flat and open universes if it is the shape we are referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to our current scientific knowledge

we know that we don't know what the 70% of the [energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy) of the Universe is. Also, a comprehensive description of the thermodynamics of the Universe is impossible with the current [standard Cosmological model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model) and Einstein's General Relativity. In particular it's very complicated, and incomplete, as I said, to talk about what is **now** the energy of the Universe. Hence, its thermodynamical evolution has very low sense, with the current knowledge. It's only a speculative subject.

For a more satisfactory answer, I can give you  a brief naive explanation of why one can't talk about the energy of an evolving Universe. As you know and as we currently believe, we live in an [expanding Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanding_Universe). This is not a steady state, there is a precise time-line and a temporal asymmetry in its evolution, hence you can't define a globally a well defined conserved charge called energy, in the sense of the [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether_theorem). You can define energy only locally, according to the [equivalence principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle). Also, there is another problem called [quantum vacuum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Vacuum#Energy) whose energy is non-null and may even increase with the expansion of the Universe.

Comment: Probably, you could be interested in this page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_fate_of_the_universe), if you didn't know it yet!